# Excel find bucket without nested IFs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have to separate my data in category, say for example:

```
Category    Minimum    Maximum
   A         -100        -20
   B         -20          0
   C           0         +20
   D         +20         +100
```

So if one data point is -50, it belongs to Category A.

One solution is to use nested IFs:

```
=IF(A1<-20,"A",IF(A1<0,"B",IF(A1<20,"C","D")))
```

But when the number of categories increases it becomes quite messy. Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the table with categories in Y2:Y10 and the minimums in Z2:Z10 (with 20 not +20 and similar for all positive numbers) then you can use a LOOKUP formula

`=LOOKUP(A1,Y$2:Y$10,Z$2:Z$10)`

Assumes there are no gaps in the ranges, i.e. the maximum for each category is effectively assumed to be immediately beow the next minimum

Comment: You have inverted the 2 ranges in your formula, it should be `=LOOKUP(A1,Z2:Z10,Y2,Y10)` - otherwise it works fine, thanks.

Comment: Yes you are correct, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be using named ranges.

I would modify your example to this:

```
Category    Minimum    Maximum
Cat_A         -100        -20
Cat_B         -20          0
Cat_C           0         +20
Cat_D         +20         +100
```

Then mark the data from Cat_A to +100, and use `Make from selection` (On *Formula* Tab, Section *Defined Names*) - use *make from left column*.

The you will get 4 named ranges Cat_A, Cat_B, Cat_C and Cat_D, which you can use in your workbook for i.e. conditional formatting, unsing `Min(Cat_A)` and `Max(Cat_A)` as limits.

However, this solution is more an extention to the one of barry houdini.

Answer (score 0):

I use this trick for equal data bucketing. Suppose you have data in `A1:A100` range. Put this formula in B1:

```
=MAX(ROUNDUP(PERCENTRANK($A$1:$A$100,A1) *4,0),1)
```

Fill down the formula all across B column and you are done. The formula divides the range into 4 equal buckets and it returns the bucket number which the cell A1 falls into. The first bucket contains the lowest 25% of values.

Adjust the number of buckets according to thy wish:

```
=MAX(ROUNDUP(PERCENTRANK([Range],[OneCellOfTheRange]) *[NumberOfBuckets],0),1)
```

**The Advantage**
The advantage of this solution is that you do not have to worry about the min and max of each bucket. The min and max parameters will **mysteriously** adjust themselves keeping equal number of observation in each bucket.